# Naming convention - isEnable vs isDisable

Tags: coding-style, boolean, naming-conventions

Let say you are using an API and you need to set a value to enable or disable a component.

Would you prefer to have:

```
control.isEnable = true
```

or

```
control.isDisable = false
```

Imo, the first one seems more "intuitive" but do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double negatives are bad in plain English as well as computer code.

You don't disagree ?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Names which form questions such as `isFoo` imply an accessor.

```
if (control.isEnabled())
```

For the name of a field I'd prefer an adjective.

```
control.enabled = true
```

Even if you preferred the question form, it should use the past-participle form, i.e., `isEnabled`. Nothing is ever described in English as "is enable".

As for positive/negative I agree with NimChimpsky 99% of the time. The application that I'm building now has an example of the other 1% where the expected state was "okay" and I needed an adjective to describe the negative case--in this case `rejected`.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers should use the sense that the caller is more apt to be interested in.  In some cases, that may imply having more than one property for things that might at first glance seem to be redundant.  For example, an interface might offer both `IsWritable` and `IsImmutable` properties.  Although something which was writable couldn't be immutable, and vice versa, it would be possible for an object to be neither writable nor immutable (e.g. it might be a live read-only view of data which could be changed by something else).  Code which wants to write to an object should test `IsWritable`; code which wants to know whether an object should be defensively copied should test `IsImmutable`.

Note that some classes in .net violate this principle.  For example, according to this principle, the property that tests the validity of a `WeakReference` should be called `IsDead`, since code which will take action if a `WeakReference` has died may not be interested in the reference if it's alive, but code which will take action if a reference is alive should almost always capture `Target` and test the whether it's `null`, rather than testing whether the `WeakReference` is alive.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with using the sense "the caller is more apt to be interested in", another option is to consider making the default, initial case `False` so it is already valid when created and doesn't need to be initialised to `True`.